# Get json item phone_number from telegram api

Tags: php, json, telegram, telegram-bot

Get `json` from:

```
https://api.telegram.org/--token--/getUpdates
```

Return:

```
stdClass Object
(
[ok] => 1
[result] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[update_id] => 122101947
[message] => stdClass Object
(
[message_id] => 36
[from] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 88132232
    [is_bot] => 
    [first_name] => Mike
    [last_name] => Christ
    [username] => mike_ch
    [language_code] => en
)

[chat] => stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 88132232
    [first_name] => Mike
    [last_name] => Christ
    [username] => mike_ch
    [type] => private
)

[date] => 1512046846
[contact] => stdClass Object
(
    [phone_number] => +905394792446
    [first_name] => Mike
    [last_name] => Christ
    [user_id] => 88132232
)
)
)
)
)
```

Now i want to get `phone_number`:

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents($getUpdate));
echo $update->result[0]->message->contact->phone_number;
```

It return nothing and errorlog is:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$contact in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/public_projects/xxx/seller/modules/telegram.php
>   on line 10
>
> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/public_projects/xxx/seller/modules/telegram.php
>   on line 10

But i am able to get successfully `date` or `chat` like this:

```
echo $update->result[0]->message->chat->first_name;
```

Any suggestion?

**Edit:** my `php` code:

```
function getUpdate(){
global $token;
$getUpdate = "http://api.telegram.org/" . $token . "/getUpdates";

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents($getUpdate));
echo $update->result[0]->message->contact->phone_number;
}
```

Comment: My only guess is If you are doing it in the loop, you might get different results from `file_get_contents($getUpdate)`. Your code should work as expected see this [example](https://3v4l.org/7OXJk)

Comment: @zstate I don't think so, because previous array like `message->chat->first_name` return right, but only `phone_number` not return. your example working good.. but after all, i updated my question with whole codes, look there is no loop here, right?

Comment: This you did should work  think. Isnt it working ? $update->result[0]->message->contact->phone_number;